# Using matchesQuery and include twice parse.com javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, include

I use include and matchesquery twice, though, on the second matchesquery, the restriction is not accepted. For example, in my code :

```
function findMe(){
var controller = Parse.Object.extend("Controller"); 
var controllerType = Parse.Object.extend("ControllerType"); 
var Type = Parse.Object.extend("TypeMagazia");
var CategoryMagazia = Parse.Object.extend("CategoryMagazia");   


    var queryControllerType = new Parse.Query(controllerType);
    var queryType = new Parse.Query(Type);          
    var queryCategoryMagazia = new Parse.Query(Type);   


    //start type 
    var typeTable = [];
      var cafebar = document.getElementById('cafe_bar');
      var club = document.getElementById('club');
      var restaurant = document.getElementById('restaurant');         
      var pistes = document.getElementById('pistes');
      //perasma value ston pinaka
      if(cafebar.checked){ typeTable.push(cafebar.value);}
      if(club.checked){ typeTable.push(club.value);}
      if(restaurant.checked){ typeTable.push(restaurant.value);}
      if(pistes.checked){ typeTable.push(pistes.value);}
      console.log(typeTable);

     //start category 
    var categoryTable = [];
    for( var i =0; i<5; i++){
    var cat = "cat"+i;
    console.log(cat);
      var category = document.getElementById(cat);
      //perasma value ston pinaka
      if(category.checked){ categoryTable.push(category.value);}
    }
     console.log(categoryTable);



    for (var i = 0; i<typeTable.length; i++){
for (var j = 0; j<categoryTable.length; j++){

                    queryControllerType.exists('objectId');

                    queryType.equalTo("TypeName", typeTable[i]);
                    queryCategoryMagazia.equalTo("CategoryName", categoryTable[j]);



                    queryControllerType.include('TypeMagaziaID');
                    queryControllerType.include('CategoryMagaziaID');                       

                    queryControllerType.matchesQuery('TypeMagaziaID', queryType);
                    queryControllerType.matchesQuery('CategoryMagaziaID', queryCategoryMagazia);

                    queryControllerType.ascending('objectId')
                    queryControllerType.find().then(function(results) {
                        console.log("results.length : "+results.length);

                         for (var k = 0; k < results.length; k++) {
                             var object = results[k];                       
                             var typeB = object.get('TypeMagaziaID');
                             var catB = object.get('CategoryMagaziaID');


                             var nameType = typeB.get("TypeName");  
                             var nameCategory = catB.get("CategoryName");

                             console.log(" Id : "+object.id +" typeName : "+nameType +" CategoryName : "+nameCategory);
                         }

                 });

                }
            }
```

The results after running the code are :

'results.length : 0"

When I comment the second matchesquery and having chosen the parameter 'club' to be the first matchesquery

```
    queryControllerType.exists('objectId');

                    queryType.equalTo("TypeName", typeTable[i]);
                    queryCategoryMagazia.equalTo("CategoryName", categoryTable[j]);



                    queryControllerType.include('TypeMagaziaID');
                    queryControllerType.include('CategoryMagaziaID');                       

                    queryControllerType.matchesQuery('TypeMagaziaID', queryType);
                    //queryControllerType.matchesQuery('CategoryMagaziaID', queryCategoryMagazia);

                    queryControllerType.ascending('objectId')
                    queryControllerType.find().then(function(results) {
                        console.log("results.length : "+results.length);

                         for (var k = 0; k < results.length; k++) {
                             var object = results[k];                       
                             var typeB = object.get('TypeMagaziaID');
                             var catB = object.get('CategoryMagaziaID');


                             var nameType = typeB.get("TypeName");  
                             var nameCategory = catB.get("CategoryName");

                             console.log(" Id : "+object.id +" typeName : "+nameType +" CategoryName : "+nameCategory);
                         }

                 });
```

I'm taking these results :

> > results.length : 8  postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400  Id : 8kl40HYG9J
> >     typeName : club CategoryName : bistro postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400 
> >     Id : 91HGIQFRGj typeName : club CategoryName : disco
> >     postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400  Id : Ddw6S8hl0Z typeName : club
> >     CategoryName : cockteil postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400  Id :
> >     LtiIQXxOx6 typeName : club CategoryName : cockteil
> >     postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400  Id : Yp6j0uJLL3 typeName : club
> >     CategoryName : bistro postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400  Id : dMnMugrKfL
> >     typeName : club CategoryName : cockteil
> >     postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400  Id : hCDeYHPLO3 typeName : club
> >     CategoryName : bistro postMagaziaTypeCategory.php:400  Id : ntrrKiNaFq
> >     typeName : club CategoryName : bistro

I want to create something like this appeared on the picture : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you are not querying correctly the `categoryMagazia`..

If you look well at your first code block you are trying to query 2 times the same `Type`.

If you change these lines

```
var queryControllerType = new Parse.Query(controllerType);
var queryType = new Parse.Query(Type);          
var queryCategoryMagazia = new Parse.Query(Type);
```

To this

```
var queryControllerType = new Parse.Query(controllerType);
var queryType = new Parse.Query(Type);          
var queryCategoryMagazia = new Parse.Query(CategoryMagazia);
```

I think you will be ok.

Also it's very nice to see people continue with Parse!

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it! This is what I was trying to figure out for the last 2 days! Your observation is so helpful to me.